# Basement Toilet Ejector Pump Shaking/Knocking

Tags: plumbing, basement, toilet, pump, sewage

In my basement we have a sewage ejector system connected to the basement bathroom plumbing. This was installed by the builder when we purchased a few years ago.

A few days ago, about a minute after flushing we started hearing a loud noise - my wife thought it was a helicopter outside, but I went to check where all our machinery is and noticed the sewage ejector outflow plumbing shaking. I thought maybe something was stuck (perhaps kid flushed more than waste/toilet paper?), and gave it a hit and it stopped.

Normally, when the ejector goes off it doesn't shake at all or really make any more than "whoosh" sound.

After this happened I ran the water in the bathroom sink until the pump activated again and it worked normally.

Today, the same thing happened. After a normal flushing the whole piping started rattling and shaking.

I am wondering how to go about diagnosing this. This is not a minor shake and its not just the clunk of the check valve. The first time is actually dislodged the seal around the pipe a bit letting out some odors.

The first time I thought the problem was something hard to pump, but now I am thinking the motor is still running but there is nothing left in the pit to pump (running dry).

What can I check or do without unscrewing everything? If I need to go inside, what should I be looking for once in there?

Comment: The joys of pumping poo, first a tiny bit of plastic can get stuck on the impeller and cause paper or poo build , the best luck I have had is after multiple flushes with clean water to turn the motor CCW with a drill, sounds crazy but that’s how we found some small plastic parts? Without having to dissemble the entire unit

Comment: Status: This weekend I opened the pit. Poorly setup where the waste dumps right ontp of the motor. I cleaned off the stuck on toilet paper and I think maybe something was crusting on the wires attaching the float to the apparatus (?) I cleaned our everything I could see. I ran the pump dry and filling the pit almost to the top a few times and could never get it to repeat. I thought perhaps there was some small thing stuck inside that fell down when the motor stopped, but I am pretty sure it was just the check valve. I'll have to wait to see if it happens again before I actual disassemble.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do from outside.  "Unscrewing everything", hopefully, means unplugging it and opening the inspection cover.  You need to find the manual, read it, open the pump and inspect what's inside.  Unplug it before reaching inside of course, so it doesn't grind up your hand.

Maybe there is something in the pump that should not be there (a tampon with its string, a solid object like a toy or a piece of nylon or twine, etc).

Maybe part of the pump became loose.

Comment: We don't use the basement bathroom that often and the kids are too young to use the bathroom on their own. I am not ruling out the possibility a baby wipe was flushed, but I am trying to look for other causes and possibilities. If it were jammed with something I would expect it to seize,  eventually break it up, or for this to happen every time. This has only happened twice, about a week apart.

Comment: Well, I'm going to stand by the idea that the answer to your question is inside the pump and not on the internet. :). The vibration must be caused by an imbalance on the rotor or axle that's being spun by the motor.  Or, less likely, by a fault in the motor itself.    If it's a violent vibration the cause should be evident when you look inside.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are not flushing something from the toilet that is not supposed to be flushed. Tissues, any type of paper or anything that does not dissolve easily may be some of those things or as @jay613 mentioned, a tampon, pad or piece of a toy

Comment: Just because something says it is flushable, might be untrue.